# Generating large testing datasets

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have made a small Python script that will generate some test sets for my project.

The script generates 2 datasets with the same dimensions `n*m`. One contains binary values 0,1 and the other contains floats.

The script runs fine and generates the output I need, but if I want to scale to many dimensions the for-loop in `pick_random()` slows down my computation time.
How can I get rid of it? Perhaps with some array comprehension using `numpy`?

What throws my reasoning off is the `if-stmt`. Because the sampling should occur with a probability.

```
# Probabilities must sum to 1
AMOUNT1 = {0.6 : get_10_20,
           0.4 : get_20_30}

AMOUNT2 = {0.4 : get_10_20,
           0.6 : get_20_30}

OUTCOMES = [AMOUNT1, AMOUNT2]

def pick_random(prob_dict):
    '''
    Given a probability dictionary, with the first argument being the probability,
    Returns a random number given the probability dictionary
    '''
    r, s = random.random(), 0
    for num in prob_dict:
        s += num
        if s >= r:
            return prob_dict[num]()


def compute_trade_amount(action):
    '''
    Select with a probability, depending on the action.
    '''
    return pick_random(OUTCOMES[action])


ACTIONS = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(2, size=(n, m)))
AMOUNTS = ACTIONS.applymap(compute_trade_amount)
```

Answer (score 9):

There are already tools for choosing elements from a collection with some given probabilities. In the standard library there is [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices), which takes the values, the probabilities and the number of items you want:

```
import random

values = ["get_10_20", "get_20_30"]
#p = [0.5 * 0.6 + 0.5 * 0.4, 0.5 * 0.4 + 0.5 * 0.6]
p = [0.5, 0.5]

n = 10
random.choices(values, weights=p, k=n)
# ['get_10_20', 'get_10_20', 'get_10_20', 'get_10_20', 'get_10_20', 'get_20_30',
#  'get_20_30', 'get_20_30', 'get_10_20', 'get_10_20']
```

The other possibility is to use [`numpy.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html#numpy.random.choice) for this, which allows you to directly generate multi-dimensional data:

```
values = ["get_10_20", "get_20_30"]
p = [0.5, 0.5]

n, m = 2, 3
np.random.choice(values, p=p, size=(n, m))
# array([['get_10_20', 'get_10_20', 'get_20_30'],
#        ['get_20_30', 'get_20_30', 'get_20_30']], dtype='<U9')
```

Both approaches assume that you can combine the probabilities to a total probability for each value. The `numpy` method enforces that they sum to one, while the standard library `random` does that for you, if necessary.

Answer (score 5):

Logically you have two different forms of chance. The 'top level' to pick between `AMOUNT1` and `AMOUNT2` and then the second form to pick the function `get_10_20` or `get_20_30`. This requires you to generate *two* random numbers. A pretty expensive operation.

Secondly you're performing a cumulative sum each and every time you're looping through either `AMOUNT`. This is just a waste when you can do it once. And so you should aim to normalize your input data.

Your input format is pretty poor, what if I want a 50/50 chance, or a 1:1:1 chance. To do so a cumulative sum would work best. But lets get your input to work in a meh way.

```py
AMOUNTS = [
    {
        0.6 : get_10_20,
        0.4 : get_20_30,
    },
    {
        0.4 : get_10_20,
        0.6 : get_20_30,
    }
]

def normalize_input(amounts):
    by_value = {}
    for chances in amounts:
        for chance, value in chances.items():
            by_value.setdefault(value, 0)
            by_value[value] += chance / len(amounts)

    total_chance = 0
    output = {}
    for value, chance in by_value.items():
        total_chance += chance
        output[total_chance] = value
    return output
```

This works hunkydory and returns:

```py
{
    0.5: get_10_20,
    1.0: get_20_30,
}
```

<sub>**Note**: untested, provided purely as an example.</sub>

```py
def pick_random(chances):
    def inner(chance):
        for c in chances:
            if c >= chance:
                return chances[c]()
    return inner


CHANCES = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(n, m)))
AMOUNTS = CHANCES.applymap(pick_random(normalize_input(OUTCOMES)))
```

---

But do you really need that `for` loop? From the looks of it no, not really.
You could change your input to integers and provide your chances in *cumulative ratios* so you could have:

```py
{
    1: foo,
    2: bar,
    4: baz,
}
```

From this you can then normalize to an array, and just index the array. Using `np.random.randint` rather than `np.random.random`. The array would look like:

```py
[foo, bar, baz, baz]
```

Which would make `inner` super simple:

```py
def inner(chance):
    return chances[chance]()
```